# C++ Inheritance Constructor

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a mammal object to call the speak function from the animal class. May I know which part I get it wrong? I am new to inheritance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std ;
enum COLOR { Green, Blue, White, Black, Brown } ;

class Animal
{
public :
    Animal() : _name("unknown")
    {
        cout << "constructing Animal object " << _name << endl ;
    }

    Animal (string n , COLOR c)
    {
        cout << "Animal name: " << n << " color: " << c << endl;
    };

    ~Animal()
    {
        cout << "destructing Animal object " << _name << endl ;
    }
    void speak() const
    {
        cout << "Animal speaks " << endl ;
    }
    void move() const { }
private :
    string _name;
    COLOR _color ;
};


class Mammal : public Animal
{
public:
    Mammal (string n, COLOR c) : Animal (n, c)
    {
        cout << "Animal name: " << n << " color: " << c << endl;
    }
    ~Mammal() {}

    void eat() const
    {
        cout << "Mammal eat " << endl ;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Mammal m.speak();
    Animal b("lion", Green);
    cout << "Program exiting …. " << endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand why I cannot create the object m to call the speak function in animal.

Comment: `Mammal m.speak();` does not make much sense

Comment: You have to create the object first. Then call its member functions. In general, if you think you have a problem due to X, remove X and see if the problem disappears (X is inheritance here.)

Comment: `Mammal m("lion", Green ) ;m.speak();`

Comment: OIC, because I dont have a default constructor that is why my Mammal m shows an error

Comment: I'd recommend you to send debug stuff to `std::clog`, not `std::cout`.

Comment: @gingerPlusPlus how do I do that?

Comment: Replace `std::cout` with `std::clog`. That's everything. Data sent to `std::clog` can go to different place than data sent to `std::cout`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to split this statement

```
Mammal m.speak();
```

in two statements

```
Mammal m;
m.speak();
```

And you have to define the default constructor for class Mammal.

For example

```
Mammal() = default;
```

or

```
Mammal() {}
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn't declare a default constructor for you if there are any user-defined constructors.

```
Mammal() { }
```